# How could detect client's identify serverside using Cloudflare WARP?

Tags: cloudflare, ddos, cloudflare-warp

Our server is in DDOS attack, and many ips is from Cloudflare WARP, ex: 2a09:bac5:55f2:1028::19c:5f. Attacker use large amount of ips, and change it very often. We applied rate limit based on client's ip, but it didn't work as expect. How could we determine client's identify (ip or some other infomation) hidden behind Cloudflare WARP.

P/s: Our site is using Cloudflare DNS service.

I searched on Cloudflare but seem they complete hidden client's real IP as new policy.

Comment: Have you considered subscribing to WAF from major cloud service provider? they have build-in (and real-time) intelligence rule engine that can identify and deny the origin requests based on several criterias

Comment: Yes, but its cost is quite high for us (they said around 5000 per month)